Audio is not coming out of the HDMI port properly
After installing Ubuntu Studio 24.04, the audio from the HDMI port became unstable.
The playback is choppy and the playback speed becomes unstable when moving the mouse.
I got the same result when booting live from Lubuntu 24.04.
I also installed a Sound Blaster Z sound card, but confirmed that there is no sound.
Is there a solution?
Target environment
Motherboard: GA-H87-HD3
Sound card: Creative SoundBlaster Z
postscript
When I read other people's reports of problems around sound, I feel that there is a problem with the kernel. There is no problem with 23.10, so I will try downgrading to that kernel or upgrading to the latest kernel.

Hard to tell if the English is a translation of the Japanese. Either way I would suggest remove the Japanese.

Refuse. Japan also reads it. I thought, but it will be translated and displayed in the end, so it would be better to delete it.

This is an English only site no matter who uses it.

I think so too. I understand.

It is self-answered.
We've confirmed that downgrading to kernel v6.5.11 resolves the sound-related issue for the foreseeable future.
But that's probably not a radical solution.
I think the cause is probably that Ubuntu hasn't kept up with the changes in the kernel specification.
Currently, in the latest kernel v6.9.3 available on https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/, the HDMI output has not been improved, but the output of Sound Blaster Z seems to be normal.
